# GPU Heightmap sculpting in shader

Tags: c++, shader, hlsl

i have successfully done the sculpting implementation on CPU,

throw some guide on how to do this on GPU kindly …

i have moved the sculpting code to vertex shader but the sculpting is not accumulating in vertex shader and cant modify position in vertex shader… kindly tell me how …

```
if (SculptMode.x == 1)//Raise
{ 
    float dist = length(int2(PickedPoint.xz) - input.position.xz);
    if (dist <= BrushRadius.x)
    {
        PositionOffset += (BrushRadius.y * (cos(PI * dist / float(BrushRadius.x)) + 1.0f) * 0.5f) * DeltaTime.x * 10.0f; 
        input.position.y = PositionOffset; 
    }
}
```

I am using RWTexture2D for it like ...

```
    if (SculptMode.x == 1)//Raise
    { 
        float dist = length(uint2(PickedPoint.xz) - input.position.xz);
        if (dist <= BrushRadius.x)
        { 
            PositionOffset[int2(input.position.xz)] += BrushRadius.y * smoothstep(0, BrushRadius.x, BrushRadius.x - dist) * DeltaTime.x * 10.0f;
        }
    }
```

but still my sculpting is in spike formation ...

[image]

then

```
input.position.y = PositionOffset[int2(input.position.xz)];
```

Comment: As far as I know shaders are stateless, you will need somewhere to accumulate.

Comment: I am using RWTexture2D for it like ...

 

    if (SculptMode.x == 1)//Raise
        { 
            float dist = length(uint2(PickedPoint.xz) - input.position.xz);
            if (dist <= BrushRadius.x)
            { 
                PositionOffset[int2(input.position.xz)] += BrushRadius.y * smoothstep(dist, BrushRadius.x, BrushRadius.x - dist) * DeltaTime.x * 10.0f;
            }
        }

Comment: what is causing quantization effect i don't know ...

Comment: any update on this .....?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed implementation to completely different method, this wont work as i think this quantization is happening because there are vertex which are shared among triangles and sculpting adjustment is applied multiple times to same vertex, that is why spikes…

Answer (score 0):

While I can't say this for certain, it looks like your issue might be that you're just not reaching some pixels. If you show the whole shader and where you dispatch it I might be able to confirm. The way that you are indexing points in the texture could be the whole problem.

The other issue I can see being possible is that you are reading and writing from the same data structure (input) - while you only read from x and z, and only write to y, this could still cause trouble as xyz are still part of a single element, which gets set all at once.

Comment: duh .................................... already done  tweaking ... and ur incorrect ... i can freely set xyz values of single RWTexture2D

Comment: Then please mark your question as solved and list the solution.